# How can i practice eugenics without getting caught?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made myself a nice artificial village, however I *severely* underestimated the number of villagers it would create:

[image]

I now have a couple hundred villagers all crammed in this tiny spot here, and as you can see with the hearts, they aren't showing any signs of stopping.

This isn't a bad thing, as I am after that one villager who sells me the coveted 'Mending' enchanted book. There's just one problem: all these *other* villagers that get in my way and have relatively worthless trades.

For these "lesser" individuals, I could just slay them with my sword, but there are several iron golems who ruthlessly seek revenge as soon as I touch any of them. Turns out not everyone shares my vision of a perfect world with perfect trades.

I could also let them free, but that would be disastrous: I'd never get them back into my <s>jail</s> custom-built house. It'd be like herding cats. And I don't know if you've ever had a villager stuck inside rows of doors, but they open and close them *incessantly*.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. I do **not** want to accidentally kill any child villagers for any reason, because I want to see their trades once they become adults
2. I **do** want to kill any villagers with worthless trades at my discretion.
3. I do **not** want to aggro Iron Golems in any way, because I value my life
4. I do **not** want to kill Librarians until after I've traded with them enough to see what their second enchanted book is. I also want to keep Farmers, as they are my primary income for emeralds.
5. I am in Survival on Bedrock Edition, so command blocks, cheats, and anything in Creative Mode are off the table.

How can I safely cull villagers who don't offer meaningful trades while preserving those villagers that do?

Comment: There are plenty of videos on YouTube that can help achieve this. Check out [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/UTmWL8yr0vA)

Comment: Your doors are mostly useless. They need a difference between number of skylight 15 blocks in front and behind them to count.

Comment: What version are you in? The villagers shouldn't spam doors anymore, it was fixed recently.

Comment: That would be cruel!

Answer (score 3):

Place blocks in a checkerboard pattern, two blocks high. Or since you already have a crowd, dig out block in a checkerboard, two blocks deep. If you are careful you can walk over them without falling in, but all villagers will quickly become trapped in 1x1 pits. Then for each pit, check if there are any villagers you want to keep. If not, pour a lava bucket in the pit for 2 seconds. Since the villagers only take "environmental" damage, this will not provoke any golems.